# Calling a python script on a different computer programmatically and getting an access denied error

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I'm trying to execute a python script that lives on a different server from the application server that calls it. I'm using IronPython to call the script. It seems like I have it wired up correctly as it attempts to process the script, but I get the error "Access to the path '\devSCRENG01\share\remotetest.py' is denied". I definitely have access to that folder which makes me think IronPython is using some credentials I'm not aware of. Does anyone know how I can explicitly set credentials for this kind of process?

I've verified that the path does exist and that I can access it using windows explorer

```
private void ExecutePythonScript()
        {
            this.UpdateProcessStatus("Refreshing iMath Model...");

            //1: Create Engine
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

            //2: Provide Script and Arguments
            var script = @"\\devSCRENG01\share\remotetest.py";
            var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(script);

            var argv = new List<string>();
            argv.Add(script);

            engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);

            //3: Execute Script
            var scope = engine.CreateScope(); 

            source.Execute(scope); //process gets access error when trying to step over this.
        }
```

The script I'm calling is a test script. When successfully processed, it will fire off an email to me and the person who wrote it.

Comment: It is good idea to confirm if code actually have access to the file by simply reading it (or even just `File.Exist`) - this way you sort out if problem is with actual file access (i.e. you misinform readers about account the code actually runs under) or if Python engine has its own restrictions (plausible as .Net had restrictions in the past on code that tries to run from shares... also I don't think it would apply here)

Comment: Alexei Levenkov, good advice, but I'm not sure how to check which user account is actually being used to execute the code. Which assembly can I use to check File.Exist? Seems that it would also include some means for seeing which credentials are being passed during debugging. Please advise.